# Merge 3 structurally identical tables if value in date column exists in all 3

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have a mysql db/server that has 3 tables that are identical in structure:
west, midwest and east.

I would like to create a national table with the sum of the columns of those regional tables, ONLY if the datetime row matches all 3 tables. That way if one hour is missing in a particular table, I don't end up summing 2 regions and calling it national.

Here is how I am thinking to do it:

All 3 tables have a datetime column.

Merge the tables (union?) only if the datetime row exists in all 3 tables.

Aggregate (sum) the columns grouped by datetime column. I would of course be summing all  columns which carry int values.

I am not sure how to run a query that would perform this task.
These tables have 11mil rows so an efficient way would be great.
I am also open to other approaches to solve this problem.

---

I picked the answer from Neil because although the answer would not work if datetime col is not unique i.e. multiple rows in Table1 with the same datetime. Using any other method the performance I got was horrific, hours of query time. I decided to compromise. I created 3 new tables
westh, midwesth and southh.
These 3 new tables are a creation of aggregating the original tables by hour.
I then used Neils second version with a twist:

```
INNER JOIN Table2 USING (datetime)
```

While datetime is indexed in my tables that provides superior performance which is a firm criteria for me.

Comment: You want to match rows from the 3 tables only if the datetimes match exactly? To the fraction of a second?

Comment: @orim datetime column is in hourly format...so to the hour

Comment: and as you mentioned, the `dtcol` is not unique within a table? So, there could be two rows in table `west` with same datetime ?

Comment: @orim yes there could be rows in table west with the same datetime. What makes the table unique is datetime-name (name is the column following datetime col) that combination is unique

Comment: @orim i just want to add that i want to sum everything in all 3 tables every hour (datetime is hourly). but if that hour is completely missing from one of the tables then i would rather leave a gap than aggregate 2 regions

Comment: If you use `@ypercube` then ypercube is notified for your comment. So, you shouldn't use `@orim` in your comments (unless you mean to notify youself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First version:

```
SELECT T123.dtcol, SUM(T123.intcol) AS intcolsum
  FROM (
    SELECT Table1.dtcol, Table1.intcol FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT Table2.dtcol, Table2.intcol FROM Table2
    UNION
    SELECT Table3.dtcol, Table3.intcol FROM Table3
  ) T123
  GROUP BY T123.dtcol
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Second version:

```
SELECT Table1.dtcol, Table1.intcol + Table2.intcol + Table3.intcol AS intcolsum
  FROM Table1 T1
  INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.dtcol = T1.dtcol
  INNER JOIN Table3 T2 ON T3.dtcol = T1.dtcol
```

Comment: @orim - i used your second version. i did a couple of modification tho. I created 3 new tables westh, midwesth, easth that has each of the 3 tables aggregated by hour so that the hour col is now unique and i used  INNER JOIN Table1 USING (datetime) since datetime is indexed in my table. that gave me superior performance over any other method. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT A.dtcol, SUM (A.intcol) intcolsum FROM
(
SELECT 'T1' T, T1.* FROM Table1 T1
UNION
SELECT 'T2' T, T2.* FROM Table2 T2
UNION
SELECT 'T3' T, T3.* FROM Table3 T3
) A
WHERE A.dtcol IN
(
SELECT T1.dtcol 
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.dtcol = T1.dtcol
INNER JOIN Table3 T2 ON T3.dtcol = T1.dtcol
)
GROUP BY A.dtcol
```

Comment: Why do you need the UNION and the JOIN?

Comment: because I don't know enough about the data model... for example: is dtcol "unique" within one table or can there be more than one row per table with the same dtcol value etc. ?

Comment: @orim dtcol is not unique, so there can be more than one row with the same datetime

Comment: OK. You are right about that, more info is needed. But if `dtcol` are unique then this is not very efficient.